# Is generation and recombination same in extrinsic semiconductors?

Tags: analog, semiconductors

For example, if we have an n - type semiconductor, so there are more electrons in the conduction band. So wouldn´t the recombination rate increase, opposed to the generation rate, because there are more electrons and so there is a higher chance for the holes to be filled.

Comment: You can see the relationships [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N88xj.png).

Answer (score 1):

Yes but there are constantly more  electrons  generated by the transition  of a electron from the donor level to the conduction band.

And as it turns out in thermal equillibrium the rate of generation of electrons from the donor level>the rate of recombination thats why we have excess electrons in n type semiconductors

Comment: If the **rate** of generation is greater than the **rate** of recombination, why don't all of the electrons eventually move to the conduction band?

Comment: Because recombination doesnt only happen for electrons coming from the donor level but also from the electrons generated in hole-electron pair generation from the valence band of the intrinsic semiconductor atoms.